# Python e Kivy: Como selecionar e copiar todo o texto de um Text Input

Tags: python, python-kivy, kivy

Olá!

Estou tentando aprender Kivy...

1) Gostaria de selecionar todo o texto dentro de um Text Input em Kivy. **Qual atributo devo estudar para eu mesmo alterar meu código?**;

2) Após selecionar todo o texto, o botão copiar deveria copiar o texto. **Qual atributo devo estudar para eu mesmo alterar meu código?**;

3) Assunto a parte: como fazer para  que os caracteres com acento sejam reconhecidos? **Não sei nem como perguntar para pedir que me indiquem o que eu devo pesquisar para corrigir isso.**

Exemplo arquivo: **main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Meu primeiro app'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Exemplo arquivo: **main.kv**

```
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        text: "Título do meu app"
        font_size: '60sp'
        top: 350
    TextInput:
        text: "Escreva aqui seu texto"
        height: "350px"
        width: 350
        top: 500
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,}
    Button:
        text: "Botão 1"
        height: 40
        width: 120
        top: 140
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4,}
    Button:
        text: "Botão 2"
        height: 40
        width: 120
        top: 140
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6,}
    Button:
        text: "Selecionar"
        height: 40
        width: 120
        top: 95
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4,}
    Button:
        text: "Copiar"
        height: 40
        width: 120
        top: 95
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6,}
```

Comment: A questão está clara e objetiva. Sobre o código concordo que poderia estar mais completo, porém, preferi apresentar só essa parte, pois é melhor apresentar algo limpo do que uma bagunça que nem eu estava entendendo. Eu não preciso que mexam no código. Apenas preciso de uma indicação: qual atributo para selecionar o texto eu devo estudar? Você pode fazer uma indicação?

Comment: já tentei até usar o exemplo dessa página ---> https://coredump.pt/questions/50433534/python-kivy-how-to-select-a-textinput-without-mouse-click <--- mas não funciona. Inclusive já tentei reproduzir igual como está, mas a janela fica toda preta.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, seja bem vindo ao mundo kivy!

> 1) Gostaria de selecionar todo o texto dentro de um Text Input em Kivy. Qual atributo devo estudar para eu mesmo alterar meu código?;

Isso é possível com o método `select_all()` do TextInput ou então usar o atalho `ctrl + a`. Caso queira copiar somente um texto selecionado dentro do TextInput, use o método `selection_text()`.
Exemplo:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: texto
        hint_text: "Escreva aqui seu texto"
    Button:
        text: 'Selecionar'
        on_release:
            texto.select_all()
```

> 2) Após selecionar todo o texto, o botão copiar deveria copiar o texto. Qual atributo devo estudar para eu mesmo alterar meu código?;

Use o método `copy(data='')` do TextInput ou então usar o atalho `ctrl + c`. Com o método copy(data='') você pode passar um texto como atribuição para o parâmetro data copy(data = 'algum texto aqui') ou então caso você não passe nada, ele copiará tudo que estiver selecionado em seu TextInput. Exemplo:

```
Button:
    text: 'Copiar'
    on_release:
        texto.copy()
```

> 3) Assunto a parte: como fazer para que os caracteres com acento sejam reconhecidos? Não sei nem como perguntar para pedir que me indiquem o que eu devo pesquisar para corrigir isso.

Isso é possível carregando o script do kivy `script.kv` pelo `Builder.load_string()` modificando o encoding para `utf-8`. Exemplo:

home.kv

```
<Home>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'ÁLGÙÑ TÊXTÕ CÓM ÀCENTÛAÇÃO!!!'
```

home.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Home(BoxLayout):
    pass

with open('home.kv', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as screen:
    Builder.load_string(screen.read())

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()

MainApp().run()
```

Pra finalizar, segue um exemplo sintetizado com todas as suas perguntas:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

for nome in ['home']: # Dessa maneira você consegue chamar mais telas
    with open(f'{nome}.kv', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as tela:
        Builder.load_string(tela.read())

class Home(BoxLayout): pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

home.kv

```
<Button>:
    font_size: sp(30)

<Home>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: texto
        size_hint: 1, .8
        hint_text: "Escreva aqui um textão!"
        font_size: sp(30)
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .2
        Button:
            text: 'Selecionar'
            on_release:
                texto.select_all()
        Button:
            text: 'Copiar'
            on_release:
                texto.copy()
        Button:
            text: 'Colar'
            on_release:
                texto.paste()
```

Animação do Exemplo:

[image: Gif do programa funcionando.]

Referências:

- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4003
- https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.selection_text